# Can I configure a WinSCP instance to always run in the background, keeping a remote directory up to date?

Tags: background, synchronization, sftp, winscp

I like using WinSCP for keeping a remote directory up to date, but it locks up the rest of the interface while in use.  Is there any way I can configure WinSCP to run on startup (in the background) and keep a certain remote directory up to date with a local copy without impacting the rest of WinSCP's interface?

Answer (score 2):

You can run two instances of WinSCP. One for keeping remote directory up to date, the other for an interactive use.

You can have WinSCP automatically start keeping remote directory up to date. There are two ways, GUI mode and scripting.

---

**GUI mode:**

```
C:\path_to_winscp\WinSCP.exe session_name /defaults  
    /keepuptodate // C:\local_path /remote_path
```

(Line break added for readability. The `/defaults` make WinSCP skip the options dialog.)

For details, see https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline

This way you cannot make WinSCP open in the background. You have to manually press the *Minimize* button.

---

**Scripting mode:**

```
C:\path_to_winscp\WinSCP.exe /console /command "option batch abort"
    "open session_name" "keepuptodate C:\local_path /remote_path"
```

(Line break added for readability.)

For details, see https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation

If you store this command to a shortcut, you can set it's *Run* property to *Minimized*.

For both modes, you can store the command to a shortcut and move it to `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup` to have it automatically started with Windows.

---

**Minimizing to a tray:**

Minimizing to a tray is a global preference option:
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_pref_window

If you do not want to enable it globally (it would apply even to the WinSCP instance for an interactive use), add this to the command-line:

```
/rawconfig Interface\MinimizeToTray=1
```

See [Raw configuration](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/rawconfig).