# Can WinSCP be set to automatically connect to a site when it launches

Tags: winscp

I primarily use WinSCP to connect to a particular site every time I launch the program. I've read about configurations that will launch the app and connect to a site each time the computer starts (such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25478385/can-i-configure-a-winscp-instance-to-always-run-in-the-background-keeping-a-rem)), but **how can I set WinSCP to connect to a site automatically *when launching the app itself?***

Comment: This question is not about programming or software development and is not appropriate for stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

See [WinSCP Command-line Options](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline):

> The first syntax opens the site. To open site, stored in folder, use path syntax “folder/site”. You can also open workspace or all sites in site folder.

Answer (score 0):

Select your store site on WinSCP login dialog and go to [*Manage > Desktop Icon*](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login#shortcuts).

It will create a desktop icon that opens WinSCP and automatically logins to the site.

See https://winscp.net/eng/docs/integration#icons